# Clause Segmentation using Stanford OpenIE

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm in a search of a good tool for segmenting complex sentences into clauses. Since I use CoreNLP tools for parsing, I got to know that OpenIE deals with clause segmentation in the process of extracting the relation triples from a sentence. Currently, I use the sample code provided in the OpenIEDemo class from the github [repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli) but it doesn't properly segment the sentence into clauses.
Here is the code:

```
// Create the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
Properties props = PropertiesUtils.asProperties(
        "annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,natlog,openie");

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
//Annotate sample sentence
text = "I don't think he will be able to handle this.";

Annotation doc = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(doc);

// Loop over sentences in the document
int sentNo = 0;
for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      List<SentenceFragment> clauses = new OpenIE(props).clausesInSentence(sentence);
  for (SentenceFragment clause : clauses) {
    System.out.println("Clause: "+clause.toString());
  }
}
```

I expect the get as output three clauses:

- I don't think
- he will be able
- to handle this

instead, the code returns the exact same input:

- I do n't think he will be able to handle this

However, the sentence

> Obama is born in Hawaii and he is no longer our president.

gets two clauses:

- Obama is born in Hawaii and he is no longer our president
- he is no longer our president

(seems that the coordinating conjunction is a good segmentation indicator)

Is OpenIE generally used for clause segmentation and if so, how to do it properly?

Any other practical approaches/tools on clause segmentation are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the clause segmenter is a bit more tightly integrated with OpenIE than the name would imply. The goal of the module is to produce logically entailed clauses, which can then be shortened into logically entailed sentence fragments. Going through your two examples:

1. > I don't think he will be able to handle this.

   None of the three clauses are I think entailed from the original sentence:

   - "I don't think" -- you likely still "think," even if you don't think something is true.
   - "He will be able" -- If you "think the world is flat," it doesn't mean that the world is flat. Similarly, if you "think he'll be able" it doesn't mean he'll be able.
   - "to handle this" -- I'm not sure this is a clause... I'd group this with "He will be able to handle this," with "able to" being treated as a single verb.
2. > Obama is born in Hawaii and he is no longer our president.

   Naturally the two clauses should be "Obama was born in Hawaii" and "He is no longer our president." Nonetheless, the clause splitter outputs the original sentence in place of the first clause, in expectation that the next step of the OpenIE extractor will strip off the "conj:and" edge.

Comment: So, it's not a solution to my problem. @GaborAngeli, do you know any (already implemented) tool/approach for clause segmentation? I found good papers on this topic but the software part remains unpublished.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this Stanford CoreNLP parse tree visualization tool? http://nlpviz.bpodgursky.com/

I don't program, but I've been looking for CoreNLP tag groups that might signify an independent clause (stand on its own).

Your e.g.:

I don't think he will be able to handle this -

I don't think

S-NP-VP

He will be able

S-NP-VP

Handle this

VP-VB-NP

---

Another e.g. Researchers are developing algorithms to harness the force from a (MRI) to steer millimeter-sized robots

Researchers are developing

S-NP-VP

Harness the force

VP-NN-NP

steer millimeter-sized robots

VP-VB-NP

---

The red line is for the first layer, and the blue line is for the second layer

the red line is for the first layer

S-NP-VP

the blue line is for the second layer

S-NP-VP

---

Some metal ions can be harmful to cells, whereas others are necessary for biochemical reactions

Some metal ions can be harmful

S-NP-DT

Others are necessary

S-NP-NNS

---

But how that is determined is often based on questioning that can be subject to interpretations and many other states have laws that players be kept out different numbers of days.

how that is determined is often based on questioning

S-SBAR-VP

many other states have

S-NP-VB

kept out different numbers

VP-VPN-NP

---

For instance, past data on older humans and non-human primates have suggested that dietary carotenoids could slow cognitive decline.

past data have suggested

S-NP-VP

dietary carotenoids could slow

S-NP-VP

---

Combinations that I've noticed:

S-NP-VP

S-NP-DT

S-NP-NNS

S-SBAR-VP

S-VP-VB

VP-VPN-NP

VP-NN-NP

VP-VB-NP